# Vertical alignment of divs with line-height and unspecified height

Tags: html, vertical-alignment, centering, css

I'm trying to center a div vertically using line-height, without specifying a set pixel value for the line-height. I need the line-height to expand to the size of it's div. Using '100vh' works, but viewport units aren't widely supported widely enough. Setting the line-height to 100% doesn't seem to work. Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="background">

<div class="lightboxbg">
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="centerme"></div>
    </div>
</div>
    
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.background {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: AntiqueWhite;
}

.lightboxbg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%
}

.centerme {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

[And here's a jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Shambolaz/Y79PU/12/) The blue box would be centered if I could get the line-height of wrapper to expand to the height of wrapper, but I don't know how to go about doing that. Thanks for reading.

EDIT: Check out Nathan Lee's answer for a solution with table cells, Fredric Fohlin's for a pretty wild 'absolute positioning' answer, and MM Tac's for a solution using absolute positioning.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Y79PU/14/)**

**The CSS Change:**

```
.lightboxbg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
}

.wrapper {
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sweet, that looks pretty straightforward, definitely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this idea. It may suit you: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

```
.Center-Container { 
  position: relative;
}

.Absolute-Center {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

In your case the wrapper needs the relative positioning, and the "center me" the absolute positioning.

Comment: That's pretty cool, I haven't gotten it working on my current fiddle yet, but I'm still playing around.

Comment: Ok, I read your other comments, and I think I need to clearify that the "center me" element needs a height set. If the element has no height it gets as the same height as the parent.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `.centerme` with following css:

**CSS:**

```
.centerme {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px; /* negative-half of element's width*/
    margin-top: -50px; /* negative-half of element's height*/
}
```

Here is a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y79PU/16/) and here is a full page **[RESULT](http://jsfiddle.net/Y79PU/16/embedded/result/)**.

**UPDATE**

To center div for variable length is simple, just remove `height`, `width`, `margin-left`, `margin-top` reference from `.centerme` css.

```
.centerme {
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Here is a [**UPDATED DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y79PU/21/).

Comment: That's a useful solution, unfortunately my centerme object will have a variable height and width, I just used 100px as an example. Still, it could be accomplished with jQuery.

Comment: Ah cool, didn't think of that. Only thing is, its centered vertically perfectly but horizontally its off, since it measures left at 50% from the very beginning of the div. Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: Yeah, for that you can use as answered by Nathan Lee.